# How to change value property in instance class in iOS Swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift, class, swift3, properties

I made collection view programmatically and set property **multipleSelectionOn** with default value **false**
Please watch my collection view code:

```
import UIKit

class GalleryCollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController , UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {  

    open var multipleSelectionOn:Bool = false

    override init(collectionViewLayout layout: UICollectionViewLayout) {

        super.init(collectionViewLayout: layout)
        collectionView?.collectionViewLayout = layout
        collectionView!.register(GalleryCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cell")

    } 

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    print(multipleSelectionOn)

    }
    **//AND SOME ANOTHER CODE**

}
```

And call it like this:

```
let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
let galleryColVC = GalleryCollectionViewController(collectionViewLayout: layout)
galleryColVC.multipleSelectionOn = true
let galleryNav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: galleryColVC)
self.present(galleryNav, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

But changing the property in calling codes not set and show me just **false** value.

How to fix this?

Comment: Do you want to get  multipleSelectionOn value in the galleryColVC  or where do you access multipleSelectionOn after you assign it true ?

Comment: Yes i want to change it and access it  @UdayaSri

Comment: try setting it to true after self.present(galleryNav, animated: true, completion: nil). It should work.

Comment: It's not rational @MohammadSadiq

Answer (score 0):

This work for me.

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let galleryColVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "GalleryViewController") as! GalleryViewController
galleryColVC.multipleSelectionOn = true
present(galleryColVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Add your Storyboard ID as "GalleryViewController" for GalleryViewController.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

```
    var multipleSelectionOn:Bool = false {
        didSet {
            print("VALUE IS: \(multipleSelectionOn)")
            //Get true
        }
    }
```